# Entity framework LINQ - access entity field w/o fetching it

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Consider I have simple entity:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Consider I have got id only of item and and want to find all entities that price is greater than price in given item.

I can do:

```
var item = dbContext.Items.Find(id);
var found = dbContext.Items.Where(off => off.Price > item.Price);
```

Can I do this w/o fetching item from database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an inner select:

```
var found = dbContext.Items.Where(off => off.Price > dbContext.Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id).Price);
```

Comment: Ok, so `FirstOrDefault` won't be evaluted first? LINQ provider will know that it can be done on sql side?

Comment: It works but I was trying the same solution and it works suboptimally. It does an INNER JOIN with a derived table, something not very clever for big tables. So, it's better to simply query the price and filter by it.

Comment: @pwas if you want to inspect what SQL EF generates, add this to your code (before the queries): `dbContext.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);`

Comment: @pwas It will be evaluated on the server.